# How to get dynamic generated input id and values

Tags: php, laravel

I have a page that allows editing the registration form for a registration in a conference. In this form, there is a table that shows the questions that exist for that conference and then the user can associate each question with registration type trough checkboxes.

After select the checkboxes, he can click on the update button to update the registration form.

**Doubt:**

My doubt is after the user click in "update" button how to update the registration form taking into account the selected checkboxes. The checkboxes id and value are dynamic, are stored in the registration types table. So how to get the checked checkboxes in the update method so is possible to update the registration_type_questions pivot table based on the selected checkboxes?

**Question Controller:**

```
// returns the view to edit the conference registration form
        public function edit($id)
        {
            $conference = Conference::find($id);
            $registrationType = RegistrationType::where('conference_id', $id)->get();
            $question = Question::where('conference_id', $id)->get();

            return view('questions.edit')
                ->with('conference', $conference)
                ->with('registration_type', $registrationType)
                ->with('question', $question);
        }
    }
    // update the registration form based on checkboxes selected
     public function update(Request $request, $id){

        $this->validate($request, [
        // ??
        ]); 

        // ??
     }
```

**RegistrationType model:**

```
class RegistrationType extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name','conference_id',...
    ];
    public function conference(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Conference');
    }
    public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'registration_type_questions');
    }
}
```

**Question model:**

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'question', 'type', 'conference_id',
    ];

    public function registration_type(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_type_questions');
    }
}
```

**Edit conference registration form code:**

```
<form id="edit_registration_types" method="post" class="clearfix" action="{{route('rtypes.update', ['conf_id' => $conf->id])}}">

    {{csrf_field()}}

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Info</th>
                            <th scope="col">Include in registration type</th>
                            <th scope="col">Mandatory Field</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Name</td>
                            <td>
                                <i class='fa fa-check font-size-lg text-primary ml-4'></i>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <i class='fa fa-check font-size-lg text-primary ml-4'></i>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Surname</td>
                            <td>
                                <i class='fa fa-check font-size-lg text-primary ml-4'></i>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <i class='fa fa-check font-size-lg text-primary ml-4'></i>
                            </td>
                        </tr>



                        @foreach($question as $q)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$q->question}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    @foreach($registration_type as $rtype)
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                                {{$rtype->name}}
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @foreach($registration_type as $rtype)
                                        <div class="form-check">
                                            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
                                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                                for the registration type "{{$rtype->name}}"
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right mt-3" value="Update"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The much I understand, you simply want an easy way to capture dynamic checkbox info from frontend. If so, then you can simply use the html naming convention built for that. e.g. `mycheckbox[]`

Use this as all the checkbox names, and process the values at backend i.e.

```
@foreach($registration_type as $rtype)
    <div class="form-check">
        <input name="mycheckbox[]" autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ $rtype->id }}" id="{{$rtype->id}}">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
           {{$rtype->name}}
        </label>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Backend:

```
// update the registration form based on checkboxes selected
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $values = $request->get('mycheckbox');
    foreach($values as $rtype_id){
        //do whatever you want with this rtype id that was checked
```

Comment: Thanks. Im trying to do that, I need to insert the question_id, the registration_type_id of the selected checkboxes in the registration_type_questions pivot table. But I don't have a model for this table. So do you know how to insert in that pivot table? To be possible to update the form based on the selected checkboxes?

Comment: But I don't know if its working proper, with that approach "public function update(Request $request, $id){

        $values = $request->get('rtypes');
        dd($values);

    }", if all checkboxes are selected it appears "array:2 [▼
  0 => "1"
  1 => "2"
]".

Comment: The values are $rtypes, so you can simply do `RegistrationType::find($rtype_id)` to find the `registration_type_id`

Comment: Thanks but the ids of the registration types are already in the view. The issue is how to get these registration types ids of the selected checkboxes and store in the pivot table "registration_type_questions" the registration_type_id  of the selected checkboxes and the question_id of each question.

Comment: @JohnZ Calm down and read my answer again. The rtypes are the 1 and 2 you get in your values dump

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Im not understanding. The 1 a 2 are the id´s of the registration types, so why is necessary to find with "RegistrationType::find($rtype_id)"? Is it not only necessary to insert in the pivot table "registration_type_questions" the registration type id´s of the selected checkboxes and the question id?

Comment: I only assumed you would need to find out which questions you're associating them with but you get the point.